# How to read cookie in view MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I have a list of comment objects in the view. Each comment has one cookie that mark the status from user action. Example: like, spam,...

In the view, I want to read the corresponding cookie of each comment to display the right view to user. Example: user A who liked comment B then the view will display the unlike button

I don't want to read cookie in the controller because the return data is a list of comment objects.

My question is how to read cookie directly in view of MVC3?

Comment: Could you add an another column in your View Model? So, while preparing the comment list in controller, you could prepare the status for each comment. Now the important logic is already done in your controller. Now your View can decide what should be done?

Comment: @PKKG: The comment object does not contain the like status field. But if this does, this will create a corresponding column in the database, because my project has been build by code first method, and I don't like this way. Do you have any solution for reading cookie in View?

Answer (score 20):

In razor view within @{ } block use below code.

```
string val = "";
if (Request.Cookies["CookieName"] != null) {
    val = Request.Cookies["CookieName"].Value;        
}
```

Comment: Do i need any "using"? I get this error in my view: "The name Request does not exist in the current context". I'm using asp.net core mvc.

Answer (score 4):

for Read Cookie:

```
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["Key"];
    ViewBag.MyCookie= int.Parse(cookie);
```

and show it in view As:

```
    @ViewBag.MyCookie;
```

Comment: for displaying in view directly, use 
   @HttpContext.Current.Request

Comment: The first solution is come from the controller, but I want to read cookie in View. The second solution is to get the GET variable, not to get the cookie. Can you show the different way?

Answer (score 1):

use `Request.Cookies`

> string val = Request.Cookies["CookieName"]?.Value;

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject context at the top of your view:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor context
```

Then you can use like this:

```
@{var myCookie = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["myCookie"]}
```

Depending on framework version it may also be required to register context in application (in Program.cs or Startup.cs):

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```